# Bootstrap: How to make leftmost column drop to bottom rather than top on resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

my current setup looks like this

```
Desktop
________________________________
|         |      Content        |
| Sidebar |      Content        |
|         |      Content        |
---------------------------------

Mobile
__________________
|                 |
|      Sidebar    |
|                 |
-------------------
|                 |
|   Content       |
|                 |
|                 |
-------------------
```

I want the Desktop to stay the same, but have the sidebar drop to the bottom instead

```
___________________
|                 |
|   Content       |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      Sidebar    |
|                 |
-------------------
```

Is there a way for me to make the grid system do this? Or is there another method for making sure this works? The sidebar is a template rendered on my backed with lots of content and processing involved, so I don't really want to do a hide/show sort of thing if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Sammy

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so far please. Also, I'm not understanding the 2nd illustration. Why are there 2 sidebars?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kekeoki/f5f8683d1fe220dc8d26b529816e5530 Ignore top sidebar that was my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in the following way, just use `push and pull classes`--

**working example**

```css
#content{
height:60px;
background-color: red;
}
#sidebar{
height:60px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
  content
   </div>
   <div id="sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
  sidebar
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!